# Jaspersoft Studio - Fields from Javabean with nested objects

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm using Jaspersoft studio 6 and try to add fields to the report using the "dataset and query dialog", selecting "javabean" and my entity class. When I add a field that is a nested java object, studio inserts the object instead of the sub-fields (properties) of that object. I think that in earlier versions of iReport I somehow got the subfields with a dot separator like "customer.name", "customer.email" etc.

At runtime I'm filling the report using a datasource that extends JRAbstractBeanDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

When you press  "Read attributes", the tab is populated with the attributes of the specified bean class. If they are also Java objects, you can double-click the objects to display the objects’ other attributes. 
Source: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/data-source-types